# is a character of a finite abelian group an eigenvector?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, abelian-groups, characters

at the moment I'm writing an essay for university and found a very interesting Lemma:
[lemma and proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsPpt.jpg)

It basically says that characters of a finite abelian group are the eigenvectors and there is a pretty easy calculation to the corresponding eigenvalue. I tried for hours to understand it, but right now I'm more thinking it's wrong than correct.
I tried it with the Cayley-Graph $G=(\mathbb{Z}_2^2,\{01,10\})$. It's basically a very small Hamming-Cube, which has an edge if it is exactly one bit different. The corresponding adjacency matrix is $\left(\begin{array}{rrr}0&1&1&0\\1&0&0&1\\1&0&0&1\\0&1&1&0\end{array}\right)$, the both characters and eigenvectors are for $\lambda=-2$ $\left(\begin{array}{rrr}1\\-1\\-1\\1\end{array}\right)$ and the trivial one $\left(\begin{array}{rrr}1\\1\\1\\1\end{array}\right)$ is the eigenvector to $\lambda=2$.

But for example $-2\neq\dfrac{1}{|S|}\sum_{s\in S}x(s)=\dfrac{1}{2}(-1+(-1))=-1$.

So either the Lemma is wrong (which would surprise me, as it's a renominated source) or I make some stupid mistakes.

I found this in a script of the Stanford University on the 2nd Page as Lemma 4: [link](http://theory.stanford.edu/~trevisan/cs359g/lecture06.pdf)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Eigenvectors of what?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the characters correspond to vectors $\pmatrix{1\\1\\1\\1}$, $\pmatrix{1\\1\\-1\\-1}$, $\pmatrix{1\\-1\\1\\-1}$ and $\pmatrix{1\\-1\\-1\\1}$, all of which are eigenvectors.

Comment: my examples are eigenvectors to the group of words with two bit length @GEdgar

and also thanks to @LordSharktheUnknown! but the thingn with the eigenvalues is my main issue!

Comment: What is an eigenvector of a group?  In your reference, it seems to be an eigenvector of the Cayley graph.  What is an eigenvector of a graph?  In your discussion it seems to be an eigenvector of the adjacency matrix of the graph.  Finally!  I know what an eigenvector of a matrix is.  Well, maybe, once you tell me the field.

Comment: yes I mean the eigenvector of the Cayley graph, we learned the eigenvector of a graph is defined as the same as from his adjacency matrix. in the linked image it is better described, that's true.